# Animating a CanvasTexture in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, glsl

In my code, I've created a plane that consists of a photo background and a text overlay using THREE.js

I did this by having the Plane object use a ShaderMaterial consisting of 2 texture uniforms: a photo and a canvas object. The canvas object just contains stroked text and I'm using `CanvasTexture` to convert it into a texture like so:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = `Normal 160px Helvetica Neue`;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1.0)";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeText(text, canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 4);

let textTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
```

Then in the fragment shader code, I set `gl_FragColor` to the text canvas texture if the current coordinate intersects with the text, and reverting to the photo background otherwise. The end result is a photo with the stroked text overlayed.

My problem is that I want to animate this text. For example, if I hover over the plane, I want the stroked text to get filled with a solid color.

To my understanding, I can't access the `ctx` of the canvas after converting it to a texture. My two current solutions are:

1. Through the shader, on hover, set a uniform and then shade the coordinates that lie inside the stroked lines. This sounds pretty difficult and tedious.
2. Creating a new texture with filled text and swapping out the material uniform for this on every hover. This seems expensive and I don't see any way to add easing to this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you hover the plane with your mouse, you could use any event handler to catch the event, I would use jquery, try to change opacity on hover handler :)!

Comment: @CarlosMontiel my guy this ain't DOM stuff

Comment: I think you are mixing canvas writing and three, I think you should be doing the "strokeText"  the three.js way: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text

Comment: @Chang Liu I worked with canvas before, you can still change the opacity of a text either images using an event handler. :)

Comment: @CarlosMontiel That is very interesting, Do you have an example of that?

Comment: @HelderSepu I originally did that but I only needed 2D text. Also I have vertex shader code and it would be better just to combine the photo and text so only one shader is required instead of 2.

Comment: @CarlosMontiel was the canvas that you worked with passed in as a texture to a Three.js object though? Also I'm not trying to modify opacity, my text is transparent with a white stroke and I want to fill it white on hover, not make it transparent.

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: @ChangLiu My unique solution is to use json images so it fills in an logarithm way, I do not have any example at the moment, I'm at work now, cheers!

Comment: @ChangLiu You can try to achieve the desired result, using Fabric.js. Have a look at this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-fabric-js/2111?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @CarlosMontiel lol ok excited to hear this solution!

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks, just tried using Fabric but I think because I'm using it as a shader uniform, it actually renders text even worse. I think in those cases with Three.js, most people use the Fabric canvas as a material map and not shader uniform.

Comment: Found this example http://bl.ocks.org/MAKIO135/eab7b74e85ed2be48eeb and I think it might actually be possible to change the CanvasTexture dynamically if I expose the ctx object as global